# iOS / Swift 3.0: how do you determine which rows are currently visible in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

How do you determine which rows are currently visible in a UITableViewController in Swift 3.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
tableView.visibleCells
```

This is an array of `UITableViewCell` that are currently visible in the table view.

If you just need the index paths of the visible rows, you can use:

```
tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
```

which is an array of `IndexPath` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. You just need to use…

```
tableView.visibleCells
```

From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells)…

> The value of this property is an array containing UITableViewCell
>   objects, each representing a visible cell in the table view.

Comment: I'm not sure why these are being voted down. This is indeed the way that you solve this problem.

Comment: I upvoted. Thanks for the contribution. I accepted "nathan" answer as it contained also info on the indexPath objects